# Как настроить аниматор у игрового объекта, чтоб он воспроизводил только одну анимацию по условию

Tags: c#, unity3d

проблема вот в чём. Есть игровой объект, у него прикреплен аниматор, в аниматоре всего одна анимация. Так она у него одна, она воспроизводится у него по умолчанию безусловно. Но у меня объект в BoxCollider2d настроен как триггер и этот объект должен воспроизводить анимацию только при взаимодействии с ним. Как надо настроить аниматор, чтоб единственная анимация воспроизводилась по условию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я знаю нельзя назначать условие первой анимации, но можно создать пустую анимацию назначить её первой и у же из нее сделать переход с условие к той анимации что нужна.

Кликаем правой кнопкой мыши по пустому пространству в окне `Animator`. В всплывшем окне нажимаем `Create State` затем `Empty`. Чтобы сделать пустую анимацию первой - нажимаем на неё правой кнопкой мыши и кликаем `Set as Layer Default State`. Ну а дальше делаем переход к нужной анимации с нужным условием.

Создание пустой анимации:
[image: Создание пустой анимации]

Назначение пустой анимации первой воспроизводимой:
[image: Назначение пустой анимации первой воспроизводимой]